# is array of character exactly same as string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

This is something that has bugged for a quite a while.
I am trying to declare an array of char I am aware of the fact that string is an array of char.
but what I want to know is that when I declare something for example an array of characters
note I meant characters it is not a string like

```
 char alphabet[26]={"a", "b" ,"c" ......"z"}
```

is that same as

```
char alphabet[]="abcd...z"
```

let's say I would do a bubble sort(I know is slow) to switch the alphabet order other way around is there any difference in handling those 2?
just really really curious.

Comment: The second one is one member longer (because of \0).

Comment: is there any difference for example when I call alphabet[3] they would both return "c" ? I handle them exact the same way? apart from the \0 at the end

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: thanks I have been declaring array of char the first way for a long time always wondered if I can just declare it the string way and use it like that thanks

Comment: Your first array should hold chars, i.e., `'a', 'b'`, etc., not pointers to char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a string and an array of `char` are quite different, though an array of `char` may *contain* a string.

An array is a data *type*. A *string* is a data *layout*.

An array is an object consisting of a contiguous sequence of some specified element type.

A *string* in C is, by definition, "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character" (reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.1, paragraph 1).

Although the terminating null character is part of a string, the *length* of a string defined as "the number of bytes preceding the null character".

For example:

```
char arr[10] = "hello";
```

The array `arr` has 10 elements, with values `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '\0',  '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0' }`.

The first 6 bytes of the array object `arr` contain a *string* whose value is `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }`, or, equivalently, `"hello"`.

As for your declarations, the first one is valid if you change the double quotes to single quotes:

```
char alphabet[26]={'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z'};
```

but the array `alphabet` doesn't contain a string because there's no terminating `'\0'` null character.

In your second declaration:

```
char alphabet[]="abcd...z";
```

`alphabet` is 27 bytes long, because a string literal implicitly specifies that there's a trailing null character.

One exception: If the length of the string literal is exactly the same as the specified size of the array:

```
char not_a_string[5] = "hello";
```

then there is no null terminator. This is rarely a good idea.